# Calling Tkinter root.quit() causes kernel and window to stop responding

Tags: python, tkinter, window, root, exit

```
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()

def generate():
    root.quit()

label1 = Tk.Label(root, text="Map Width:")
label2 = Tk.Label(root, text="Map Height:")
label3 = Tk.Label(root, text="Lake Size:")
e1 = Tk.Entry(root)
e2 = Tk.Entry(root)
e3 = Tk.Entry(root)
button1 = Tk.Button(root, text="Generate", command=generate)
label1.grid(row=0, column=0)
label2.grid(row=1, column=0)
label3.grid(row=2, column=0)
e1.grid(row=0, column=1)
e2.grid(row=1, column=1)
e3.grid(row=2, column=1)
button1.grid(row=3, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

This is a snippet from a larger project, with the remaining function of `generate()` removed for simplicity's sake. With the above code, a window is successfully created with three labels, three corresponding entry fields and a single button. The generate button is intended to call the function `generate()` which in turn creates a map object based on other code, and then calls `root.quit()`.

However, when the button is pressed, the window stops responding and the python kernel repeatedly prints the message:

```
It seems the kernel died unexpectedly. Use 'Restart kernel' to continue using this console.
```

I'm sure it's a minor mistake, but if anyone could show me where I went wrong I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Just to confirm, even though this is "a snippet from a larger project", you're saying that this exact code causes the behavior you're describing? What are you using to run this -- does this happen when running from the command  line (eg: python the_script.py)?

Comment: Does the following help you at all? https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3114

Comment: @Bryan Yes - running this exact code causes the problems described. However I replaced 'root.quit()' with 'root.destroy() which seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `root.destroy()` instead of `root.quit()`

`root.quit()` from my understanding this is better used when you have other code after your main loop you want to run.

```
"""Quit the Tcl interpreter. All widgets will be destroyed."""
```

`root.destroy()` will destroy everything inside your main loop. and should be used to exit a program.

This is a quote from the method in the tkinter library.

```
"""Destroy this and all descendants widgets. This will
        end the application of this Tcl interpreter."""
```